# nvidia-smi returns No devices found after system udpate

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia

I can't see any suspicious in `journalctl -b -p 3`. What else could I check?

Comment: Reinstall the Nvidia packages.

Comment: @NasirRiley Did so to to no avail: `sudo pacman -S nvidia cuda nvidia-settings`